# No qualifying bean of type 'com.jpa.dao.UserRepository' available

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am trying String JPA for the first time.

I was following a Youtube video by Durgesh Sir.

This is the error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.jpa.dao.UserRepository' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:351)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:342)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1177)
    at com.jpa.demo.BootjpaApplication.main(BootjpaApplication.java:13)
```

Following are my files

BootjpaApplication.java (which contains main)

```
package com.jpa.demo;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import com.jpa.dao.UserRepository;
import com.jpa.entities.user;
@SpringBootApplication
public class BootjpaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context= SpringApplication.run(BootjpaApplication.class, args);
        UserRepository userrepo= context.getBean(UserRepository.class);
        user user=new user();
        user.setName("Varun Dhawan");
        user.setCity("Paris");
        user.setStatus("happy");
        user user1= userrepo.save(user);
        System.out.println(user1);
    }
```

user.java (there are 4 variables. id is auto generated. Other 3 have getters and setters.

```
package com.jpa.entities;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class user {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy =GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    
    private String name;
    private String city;
    private String status;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
    public user(int id, String name, String city, String status) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.city = city;
        this.status = status;
    }
    public user() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "user [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", city=" + city + ", status=" + status + "]";
    }
    
}
```

UserRepository.java

```
package com.jpa.dao;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.jpa.entities.user;
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<user,Integer> {
    
}
```

Application.properties

```
spring.datasource.name=jpa
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jpa
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root@123
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Thank you!

Comment: What package does `BootjpaApplication` reside in? It needs to be in the root package for all other beans to be picked up by component scan

Comment: @crizzis 
UserRespository is in com.jpa.dao,
BootjpaApplication is in com.jpa.demo,
user.java is in com.jpa.entities.
What do you mean by root package?

Comment: I got it. @crizzis Thank you so much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your packages are not scanned properly.

Can you please try adding `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.jpa")` instead of `@SpringBootApplication`.

Comment: what's the package name for BootjpaApplication class?

Comment: UserRespository is in com.jpa.dao,
BootjpaApplication is in com.jpa.demo,
user.java is in com.jpa.entities.

Comment: hey, thanks for bringing the package in notice. The error was due to BootjpaApplication not being in the root package. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I also followed durgesh sir videos , I fixed my code by keeping it in same package , then it worked

Comment: I see this is your first answer, which is awesome. But since there's already an accepted answer, new answers should try to improve on it, or at least update outdated information. Your answer will probably work, but it's a little hacky and doesn't really address the issue in the question.

Answer (score 0):

just create a single package(forget about coupling for a bit and do that). Then put all the classes(POJO , Main) and Interface(UserRepository) in side that package and re-start your project. It will work.

Comment: I see this is your first answer,  which is awesome.
But since there's already an accepted answer, new answers should try to improve on it, or at least update outdated information.
Your answer will probably work, but it's a little hacky and doesn't really address the issue in the question. 
But please keep at it :)

Answer (score 0):

your package structure should be like this,
`com.spring`
`com.spring.DAO`
`com.spring.Model`
`com.spring.View`
`com.spring.Controller`

Answer (score 0):

In pom.xml file checks for hibernate and JPA configuration

Same bug occur in my application

I resolve it by adding configuration

```
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues with Repository not being found. So what I did was to move everything into 1 package. And this worked meaning that there was nothing wrong with my code. I moved the Repos & Entities into another package and added the following to `SpringApplication` class.

```
@EnableJpaRepositories("com...jpa")
```

```
@EntityScan("com...jpa")
```

After that, I moved the Service (interface & implementation) to another package and added the following to SpringApplication class.

```
@ComponentScan("com...service")
```

This solved my issues.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your package name. The package name should be in a hierarchical manner.
like

```
com.jpa.test  
com.jpa.test.dao  
com.jpa.test.entities
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is location of the main class. The main class should be in the base package i.e. com.jpa in your case. Your main class is inside com.jpa.demo. Don't make the package demo for main class.
here is an example that follows your practice of code. This should solve the problem.